# Annoying issues with wifi connectivity android

Tags: android, android-wifi

I am designing an app for IoT(internet of things) project which needs seamless connectivity between various SSIDs.

App stores SSID-pwd pair in DB and when a particular IoT device pops up in wifi scan list, it is connected to phone automatically.

I have tried following code to connect to WiFi from within my app.

```
public boolean ConnectToNetworkWEP( String networkSSID, String password )
{
    try {
        WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
        conf.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";   // Please note the quotes. String should contain SSID in quotes
        conf.wepKeys[0] = password;  //WEP password is in hex, we do not need to surround it with quotes.
        conf.wepTxKeyIndex = 0;
        conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
        conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);

        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);

        List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
        for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
            if(i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + networkSSID + "\"")) {
                wifiManager.disconnect();
                wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
                wifiManager.reconnect();

                Toast.makeText(this, i.SSID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
        }

        //WiFi Connection success, return true
        return true;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ex.getStackTrace()));
        return false;
    }
}
```

But it can not reliably connect to listed SSIDs. It seems to depend upon phone's native connectivity, because when I pass SSID to method without password or provide invalid password, it still connects to the network whose SSID is given.
But when I forget all networks, then it fails to connect with correct password.

Still crazy, irrespective of the configuration I pass to the WifiManager object for a given SSID, it connects to a phone remembered SSID which is not supplied in the configuration object.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain a little more about the problem.  It sounds like the issue is that it's still connecting with a bad password?  Is the connection always initiated from your code, or is there some network auto-authentication going on?

Comment: I actually have 2 WiFi connections that I'm checking with. I created a simple app with 2 buttons, 1 to connect to n/w 1 and another to n/w 2. I pass in n/w SSID and network key to connect to the network. At times, I pass correct details, yet wifi gets connected to the other network. At other times, i pass no/incorrect password and still the app gets connected to n/w. See my other question for more details. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29164697/android-weird-behaviour-wifimanager-connecting-to-different-network